# ccache: error: configuration setting "cache_dir" must not be the empty string

Tags: cmake, embedded, embedded-linux, buildroot, ccache

I'm using Buildroot to add a package, it shows the following error in buiding step

```sh
cmake3 --build . --target install --config Release
...
ccache: error: configuration setting "cache_dir" must not be the empty string
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
```

I tried rebuiding `host-ccache`, and in `menuconfig`, I checked `Enable compiler cache`, but it doesn't work. Can I get some help, pls?

Comment: It could be that you don't have the $HOME environment variable defined in your system?

Comment: What is your `BR2_CCACHE_DIR` setting? Sounds like it is empty... If you change its value, don't forget to run `make host-ccache-dirclean` to rebuild ccache itself.